# Restore contacts from nandroid backup

Tags: contacts, cyanogenmod, backup, nandroid

I got a nandroid backup of a stock android froyo firmware. The device (GT-I9003, Galaxy SL) is now running cyanogenmod 9. how can i transfer the contacts (and sms/mms optionally) from the backup to the running system?

Comment: TitaniumBackup pro has an 'extract from nandroid backup' feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had contact sync enabled and you added the account on this rom too your contacts should appear. If they don't, try [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dtitanium+backup) Pro. It's a terrific backup solution and it's pro version allows you to restore individual items from CWM backups.
It costs more than your average app but it's super well worth it.